# Sudoku doesn't work, probable sys.path error

Tags: 12.04, games, default-programs

As the title suggests, the default sudoku game doesn't work anymore. I used to use it quite frequently however, after a break when i tried to run it again, it doesn't open.

If I search for Sudoku on the dash and click on it, the command is registered, but nothing happens.

I'm on 12.04. How can this be fixed?

**Edit**

Upon trying to run it in the terminal as gnome-sudoku or gnome-sudoku -v, i get the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/games/gnome-sudoku", line 21, in <module>
        from gnome_sudoku.gnome_sudoku import start_game
    ImportError: No module named gnome_sudoku.gnome_sudoku
```

**Edit #2**

Paste bin links for -

1) locate gnome_sudoku

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5864729/

2)python -c "import sys; print sys.path"

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5864604/

3)grep -n "" /usr/games/gnome-sudoku

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5864607/

**Edit #3**

As lgarzo suggested, `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` may be missing from my `sys.path`, and the output for `python -c 'import os; print os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]'` is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

And upon running `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages gnome-sudoku` in the terminal I get -

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gi.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUTF8String
```

My python version is 2.7.4, how can one proceed?

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-sudoku` if it helps?

Comment: @lgarzo

I get the following error

'Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main gnome-sudoku all 1:3.4.1-0ubuntu2.2
  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnome-sudoku_3.4.1-0ubuntu2.2_all.deb  Something wicked happened resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?'

Comment: I think you should have a look at the network settings. Why is it unable to resolve `archive.ubuntu.com`? I've clicked on the „fetch” URL, and I can confirm it works. You might have a partially updated system. It should be fixed first, then update it, finally try to reinstall the `gnome-sudoku` package. If you have problems solving the above issue, you might want to ask a new question regarding the problem.

Comment: @lgarzo, you were right about the network problem, that got resolved and i reinstalled the `gnome-sudoku` package. However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please include the output of the following commands: `locate gnome_sudoku` and `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"` and `grep -n "" /usr/games/gnome-sudoku`. You can use [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: @lgarzo, done, i've added the links.

Comment: I think you mistyped `locate gnome_sudoku`. Please note the underscore `_` vs. a dash. (Or simply copy-paste.) Could you re-run this command and include it's output?

Comment: @lgarzo done, sorry for that.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is missing from your `sys.path` list. Have you set any Python environment variables (especially `PYTHONPATH`)? If not sure run this command and see its output: `python -c 'import os; print os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]'`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9612/discussion-between-projjol-and-lgarzo)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'

Comment: Try to start it from terminal again, but with: `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages gnome-sudoku`

Comment: i get this `ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/_gi.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_AsUTF8String
`

Comment: Could you tell your python version? `python --version`

Comment: 2.7.4, that's the version

Comment: I suspect that it is a path issue, i.e. the list displayed by `sys.path` is too different from my list, although I'm on 13.04, and cannot check 12.04. This is my final bet, try this long command with PYTHONPATH: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5864926/ If that does not work, well edit your question again with the missing information from the discussion (the os.environ part with the PYTHONPATH KeyError, your Python version, and maybe the first PYTHONPATH=... gnome-sudoku line) and I'm sure a brighter mind will have an answer for you.

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'. Should the new question address the problem of sudoku not working?

Comment: I think you should still keep this question, but include the above listed information. (If you opened a new, it would be a duplicate.) Editing the question and adding more information: what have you tried, and which were the results, etc. will allow the new eyes see this debug information and avoid investigating them again. The new content will make the question jump at the top of active questions, therefore unnecessary to open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it from command line/terminal

```
gnome-sudoku
```

or verbose

```
gnome-sudoku -v
```

let us know if the cmd line show any errors.

Comment: I've updated the question with the error.

Comment: Seems like you and [lgarzo](http://askubuntu.com/users/28369/lgarzo) figure out it's due to missing PYTHON in your Path variable. Cheers

Comment: yes, but what needs to found is how to rectify it. :D